# Linking files/headers in C

Tags: c, linux, compilation, linker, clang

Let's say I have the following program (`hello.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define NAME "ashoka"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello, world! My name is %s\n", NAME);
}
```

So, as I understand it the **process of compiling** this program is:

1. **Preprocessing**: will copy-paste the *stdio.h* and *math.h* functions declarations and replace `NAME` with `"ashoka"`.

   ```
   clang -E hello.c
   ```
2. **Compiling**: will turn [c](/questions/tagged/c) code into *assembly* code

   ```
   clang -S hello.c
   ```

   file produced: **hello.s**
3. **Assembling**: transform *assembly* code to *object* code

   ```
   clang -c hello.s
   ```

   file produced: **hello.o**
4. **Linking**: combine *object* files into one file that we will execute.

   ```
   clang hello.o -lm
   ```

   OR (let's say I also want to link hello2.o)

   ```
   clang hello.o hello2.o
   ```

---

So, here come the questions:

1. Is the process described the correct one?
2. In the linking stage, we link together `.o` (Object code) files. I know that `math.h` resides in `/usr/include` directory. Where is `math.o`? How does the linker find it?
3. What are `.a` (static libraries) and `.so` (dynamic libraries) in Linux? And how are they related with `.o` files and the linking stage?
4. Let's say I want to share a library I made with the world. I have a `mylib.c` file, in which I have declared and implemented my functions. How would I go about sharing this so that people would include it in their projects by doing either `#include <mylib.h>` or `#include "mylib.h"`?

Comment: Your code will emit compile error due to absence of closing `"`

Comment: @MikeCat thx. Edited.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I will also create a new post about question 4 after I've done some research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, though going through assembly is an extra step (you can just compile the C source to an object). Internally, the compiler will have many more stages: parsing code into an AST, generating intermediate code (e.g. LLVM bitcode for `clang`), optimizing, etc.
2. `math.h` just defines protypes for the standard math library `libm.a` (which you link with `-lm`). The functions themselves live in object files archived inside `libm.a` (see below).
3. Static libraries are just archives of object files. The linker will check what symbols are used and will extract and link the object files that export those symbols. Those libraries can be manipulated with `ar` (for example `ar -t` lists the object files in a library). Dynamic (or shared) libraries are not included in the output binary. Instead, the symbols your code needs are loaded at runtime.
4. You would simply create an header file with your `extern`ed prototypes:

   ```
   #ifndef MYLIB_H
   #define MYLIB_H

   extern int mylib_something(char *foo, int baz);

   #endif
   ```

   and ship it with your library. Of course the developer must also link (dinamically) against your library.

The advantage of static libraries is reliability: there will be no surprises, because you already linked your code against the exact version you're sure it works with. Other cases where it may be useful is when you're using uncommon or bleeding-edge libraries and you don't want to install them as shared. This comes at the cost of increased binary size.

Shared libraries produce smaller binaries (because the library is not in the binary) with smaller RAM footprint (because the OS can load the library once and share it among many processes), but they require a bit more care to make sure you're loading exactly what you want (e.g. see [DLL Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell) on Windows).

As @iharob notes, their advantages don't just stop at binary size. For example, if a bug is fixed in a shared library all programs will benefit from it (as long as it doesn't break compatibility). Also, shared libraries provide abstraction between the external interface and the implementation. For example, say an OS provides a library for applications to interface to it. With updates, the OS interface changes, and the library implementation tracks those changes. If it was compiled as a static library, all programs would have to be recompiled with the new version. If it was a shared library, they wouldn't even notice it (as long as the *external* interface stays the same). Another example are Linux libraries that wrap system/distro-specific aspects to a common interface.

Comment: I like your answer very much, but *you're not loading an incompatible version* is a bit misleading. It's pretty safe to assume that if your code was compiled against the correct version of the library and linked with it, there will be no surprises. Also, shared libraries have many advantages over static ones besides the size of the binaries. A complete OS without shared libraries would be challenging for example.

Comment: @iharob Reworded that part and added more on shared libs.

Comment: @AndreaBiondo Great answer. But you made me have one more question. Please look at newly created question 4.

Comment: @padawanTony Added some info on that, but you're getting pretty broad here (distributing shared libs would really need a separate answer). I suggest you look up some tutorials on shared libs, they'll walk you through compilation (e.g. flags like `-fpic`, `-shared`, etc) and making it work (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `-rpath`, `ldconfig`, etc).

Answer (score 4):

The process you describe above is correct.  In the vast majority of cases however, the C code is preprocessed and assembled in a single step as follows:

```
clang -c hello.c
```

Performing separate preprocessing is typically only done for debugging.  Conversion to assembly is almost never done unless you intend to do some manual assembly level optimization, which is rarely necessary.

With regard to linking, the `-l` option tells the linker to look for a shared library of the form "lib{name}.so".  In your example, `-lm` tells the linker to link with libm.so.  By default it will look in /usr/lib, however you can use the `-L` option to give it a list of directories to search for libraries.

You use the `-B` flag to switch between linking with static libraries or dynamic libraries:

```
clang hello.o -lm -Bstatic -lstaticlib -B dynamic -ldynamiclib
```

This will link with libm.so, libstaticlib.a, and libdynamiclib.so

Static libraries are linked directly to your executable like .o files are.  In contrast, dynamic libraries are kept separate from your executable and are loaded up at run time.

Comment: Great answer. But you made me have one more question. Please look at newly created question 4.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, this is the process generally.
2. There is no *math.o* file, the `-lm` switch links to *libm.so* (*a shared object, hence: .so*) where all the symbols required by math functions declared in *math.h* are **defined**.
3. Lets answer this in two sections

   **Static libraries**

   Are simply collections of object files saved in an archive format.

   **Shared libraries**

   Are (*on linux*) ELF files with symbols defined like they are defined in executable files, you link programs to be able to use these symbols at runtime and there is a loader that loads such symbols into the program to be used.

   This is pretty much the same on other platforms, like *.dll*s on windows, they are basically compiled programs that lack a *main()* function so they cannot be executed directly. Thye contain executable code to be loaded at runtime. You can do it yourself in fact by using [`dlopen(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) on linux.

---

**Note**: in the code you posted some things will not happen, because you didn't use anything from *math.h* so linking to *libm.so* is completely uneeded. Compilers also try to optimize the generated code and in your case the program is equivalent to the simplest *Hello World* in [c](/questions/tagged/c). But the rest of the question is valid and it does make sense to answer.

Comment: Great answer. But you made me have one more question. Please look at newly created question 4.

Comment: @padawanTony Glad to help, and making you have more questions is actually good. But please, ask another question. Don't edit yours after answers are already posted.